# Zend Route and Infinite Categories

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I'm building a Cms for an organization and url scheme is like this:

```
departmentName.site.edu/subDepartment/subDepartment/evenMoreSubDepartments/module/controller/action/*
```

I think i have to combine Zend_Controller_Router_Route and Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname but i don't know how.

If someone can help, i appreciate it.

Comment: I don't write it in an answer as it is only half of one : have you considered the regex route ? Here is an interesting discussion about something close : [how to use a recursive route](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/how-to-use-a-recursive-route-td671700.html)

Comment: i saw the forum topic but it's not the same situation. I want the default routes too. And regex gives parameters as 1,2,3 not controller => blabla, action => bla..